# React state with JSX elements is setting the last ref in ref array to null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a piano key component. When a key is pressed a visual is created, which is set in a state "visual" so that the component rerenders with the new visual. This visual is a div which is also assigned a ref so that I can animate it easily. I have a counter ref to key into the "visual" state and "visual_ref" ref. After 3 seconds, I delete both the ref and the visual for the div as it is offscreen. Deleting the ref works fine, but deleting the visual deletes the corresponding visual, but also sets the last visual in the visual_ref to null. I do not know why

[visual_ref.current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1f2yy.png) 3 Visuals created. visual_ref.current[counter] is correctly deleted, however set_visuals deletion of its JSX element sets the last index of visual_ref.current to null. This is not because the last ref was assigned to it

**PianoKey Component**

```
 const audio = useRef(null)

  let visual_refs = useRef([])

  let curr_animation = useRef([null, true])

  let [visuals, set_visuals] = useState([])
  let glowline = useRef(null)

  let counter = useRef(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(visual_refs.current)
    if (visuals[counter.current] && curr_animation.current[1]) {
      curr_animation.current = [attribute_animation(visual_refs.current[counter.current], 'height', '0', '300000px', 1000000), false]
    }
    
  }, [visuals])


  useEffect(() => {
    if (pressed) {
      audio.current.play()

      set_visuals(prev_state => {
        curr_animation.current[1] = true

        return ({
          ...prev_state,
          [counter.current]: (
          <div key={`${counter.current}`} ref={ref => visual_refs.current[counter.current] = ref} 
          className={`visualizer-instance ${color === 'black' ? 'black-visualizer': ''}`}></div>
          )
      })}) 
      
      attribute_animation(glowline.current, 'opacity', '0', '1', 600, 'cubic-bezier(0,.99,.26,.99)')

    } else if (!pressed && pressed !== null && counter.current in visual_refs.current && curr_animation.current[0]) {

        curr_animation.current[0].pause()
        attribute_animation(visual_refs.current[counter.current], 'bottom', '0', '300000px', 1000000)
        attribute_animation(glowline.current, 'opacity', '1', '0', 3000, 'cubic-bezier(.19,.98,.24,1.01)')

        let curr_counter = counter.current
        setTimeout(() => {
          delete visual_refs.current[curr_counter]
          // BELOW DELETES EXTRA VISUAL REF
          set_visuals(prev_state => {
            const new_state = {...prev_state}

            delete new_state[curr_counter]
            return new_state
          })
        }, 3000, curr_counter)
          
        counter.current += 1
    }
  }, [pressed])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reactjs' delete keyword is an interesting one. My lint complains when I use it.

When you call `delete new_state[curr_counter]` inside the `set_visuals` callback, you're directly modifying the existing object in the state. React expects state updates to be replacements with entirely new objects. Since you're modifying the same object in `set_visuals`, when you delete the element at `curr_counter`, all references to that object, including those in `visual_ref.current`, are also affected. By deleting the element from the state, you're deleting it from memory, causing `visual_ref.current[lastIndex]` to point to a non-existent element.

Instead of deleting the element directly, create a new object without the element you want to remove. The ... spread operator would help. If the `visuals` state is an array, you can directly manipulate it using the filter method.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. So you're saying that even though I am spreading the prev state of visuals and assigning it to a new object, it is still pointing to the original object and so using delete causes this to mutate the state?

Comment: The spread operator creates a new object with the same properties. It copies the references to the objects within the original state.